# How to create Blur Bitmap Image in Android

Tags: android, bitmapimage

i have try to create a Blue Bitmap image but it will generate an error some render script

```
private Bitmap blurRenderScript(Bitmap smallBitmap, int radius) {

    try {           smallBitmap = RGB565toARGB888(smallBitmap);         } catch (Exception e) {             e.printStackTrace();        }

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(smallBitmap.getWidth(),
            smallBitmap.getHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    RenderScript renderScript = RenderScript.create(MainActivity.this);

    Allocation blurInput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript,
            smallBitmap);       Allocation blurOutput = Allocation.createFromBitmap(renderScript,
            bitmap);

    ScriptIntrinsicBlur blur = ScriptIntrinsicBlur.create(renderScript,
            Element.U8_4(renderScript));        blur.setInput(blurInput);       blur.setRadius(radius); // radius must be 0 < r <= 25       blur.forEach(blurOutput);

    blurOutput.copyTo(bitmap);      renderScript.destroy();

    return bitmap;

}
```

and second part is

```
private Bitmap RGB565toARGB888(Bitmap img) throws Exception {       int numPixels = img.getWidth() * img.getHeight();       int[] pixels = new int[numPixels];

    // Get JPEG pixels. Each int is the color values for one pixel.         img.getPixels(pixels, 0, img.getWidth(), 0, 0, img.getWidth(),
            img.getHeight());

    // Create a Bitmap of the appropriate format.       Bitmap result = Bitmap.createBitmap(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(),
            Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    // Set RGB pixels.      result.setPixels(pixels, 0, result.getWidth(), 0, 0, result.getWidth(),
            result.getHeight());        return result;  }
```

when i calling the method `blurRenderScript(bitmap, 20)` it will generate an error like that `10-06 11:40:33.547: E/RenderScript(13094): rsi_ScriptIntrinsicCreate 5 10-06 11:40:33.571: A/libc(13094): Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV) at 0x00000000 (code=128), thread 13107`

Comment: check out this awesome library : [Blurry](https://github.com/wasabeef/Blurry)

Answer (score 0):

You can use some third party tools for this 
Blur an Image with Renderscript - Xamarin

Requirements

```
enter code here
```

This recipe will only work with Android 4.2.2 (API level 17) or higher.

Recipe

The UI for this recipe is contained in the following XML layout file:

This is a very simple UI that has an ImageView and a SeekBar. We inflate this layout and wire up an event handler to the SeekBar in OnCreate method of our activity, as shown in the following code:

When the user stops sliding their finger along the SeekBar, the StopTrackingTouch event will be fired and the BlurImageHandler method invoked. The contents of this handler maybe seen in the following snippet:

If the SeekBar has a value greater than zero, then we will need to apply a blur filter. If the value of the SeekBar is zero, then no blur needs to be applied. The code inside DisplayBlurredImage can be seen below:

Let's take a quick moment to understand DisplayBlurredImage. The first thing we do is to disable the SeekBar and display an indeterminate progress dialog. In order to keep our application responsive and to prevent an ANR (Application Not Responding) message from Android, the actual filtering will be performed in a separate thread. This example will invoke the method CreateBlurredImage via the Task Parallel Library. The Task that we created to do this work has a continuation that will update the UI with the blurred image and dismiss the progress dialog. This continuation is scheduled to run in the UI thread of our application.

The final piece of code we need to examine will perform the actual blurring of the image. The code for this is contained in the method CreateBlurredImage. This code has comments inline to help explain the relevant parts of code:

http://developer.xamarin.com/recipes/android/other_ux/drawing/blur_an_image_with_renderscript/

Comment: question doesn't ask for solution in **xamarin**